# Why won't VisualStudio let me use QStringLiteral inside a lambda if QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII is defined?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, visual-c++, qstring

We're in the process of making our codebase encoding safe via `QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII`. Everything has been working fine with gcc and clang, but under VisualStudio 2010 we have run into the following unusual compile issue.

This code:

```
#define QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII
#include <QString>
void func()
{
    auto f = [] () -> QString
    {
        QString a = QStringLiteral("Hello.");
        return a;
    };
    QString b = f();
}
```

generates this error:

```
1>example.cpp(7): error C2248: 'QString::QString' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QString'
1>          C:\Qt\5.1.1\include\QtCore/qstring.h(691) : see declaration of 'QString::QString'
1>          C:\Qt\5.1.1\include\QtCore/qstring.h(207) : see declaration of 'QString'
```

The actual constructor it's complaining about being private is `QString(const char *)`.

`QStringLiteral()` is a complex macro that does a lot of C++11 black magic, so it's not entirely surprising that an older version of VisualC++ chokes on it. The interesting thing is that the error only shows up when using `QStringLiteral()` inside of lambda when `QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII` is defined!

This compiles:

```
#undef QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII  // Note the undef!
#include <QString>
void func()
{
    auto f = [] () -> QString
    {
        QString a = QStringLiteral("Hello.");
        return a;
    };
    QString b = f();
}
```

As does this:

```
#define QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII
#include <QString>
void func()
{
    auto f = [] () -> QString
    {          
        QString a = QLatin1String("Hello."); // Note using QLatin1String() instead.
        return a;
    };
    QString b = f();
}
```

And this:

```
#define QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII
#include <QString>
void func()
{
    QString a = QStringLiteral("Hello."); // Note QStringLiteral() used outside the lambda.
    auto f = [&a] () -> QString
    {          
        return a;
    };
    QString b = f();
}
```

What is going on? It's not a critical issue; there are plenty of workarounds available, but it's just strange enough that I can't stop wondering why.

**Update:**

I had looked at the `QStringLiteral` macro before posting, but at Alf's suggestion I fully expanded it, which (after formatting for clarity) gives:

```
#define QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII
#include <QString>
void func()
{
    auto f = [] () -> QString
    {
        QString a = (   []() -> QString
                        {
                            enum { Size = sizeof(L"Hello.")/2 - 1 };
                            static const QStaticStringData<Size> qstring_literal = { { { { (-1) } }, Size, 0, 0, sizeof(QStringData) }, L"Hello." };
                            QStringDataPtr holder = { qstring_literal.data_ptr() }; 
                            const QString s(holder);
                            return s;
                        }()
                    );
        return a;
    };
    QString b = f();
}
```

This generates the exact same error, which now suggests that the compiler things the return type of the lambda call is `char *`, despite it explicitly having a return type of `QString`. However, making one small-ish change results in something that does compile:

```
#define QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII
#include <QString>
void func()
{
    auto f = [] () -> QString
    {
        auto qsl =  []() -> QString
                    {
                        enum { Size = sizeof(L"Hello.")/2 - 1 };
                        static const QStaticStringData<Size> qstring_literal = { { { { (-1) } }, Size, 0, 0, sizeof(QStringData) }, L"Hello." };
                        QStringDataPtr holder = { qstring_literal.data_ptr() }; 
                        const QString s(holder);
                        return s;
                    };
        QString a = qsl();
        return a;
    };
    QString b = f();
}
```

So apparently attempting to call `operator()` on the lambda definition directly just confuses the compiler into doing I-don't-know-what. The crazy thing is that if `QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII` isn't defined, the `QString(const char *)` constructor is no longer private and presumably the compiler somehow successfully uses it on the result of the lambda call, despite the fact that the lambda doesn't return a `char *`

Comment: why don't you check [C:\Qt\5.1.1\include\QtCore/qstring.h(691)] for the declartion of the relevant constructor. as i recall from another SO question the qstringliteral thing adds an L prefix to the literal and passes it to a lambda that uses it to construct a static that it returns. not very advanced stuff, should be not too difficult to un-nest i think.

Comment: It looks like a compiler bug to me. Qt probably should disable the C++11 magic in `QStringLiteral` for that compiler. Do you have the latest service pack installed for your VS?